# how to draw red line on teechart of delphi

Tags: delphi-7, teechart

I need to draw teechart look like the picture.
how to draw red line on teechart of delphi?

[image]

Comment: It's a line series with three points.

Comment: Add a `TFastLineSeries` using the "stairs" format to create the red dashed lines.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a `TLineSeries` for the line data, add a `TFastLineSeries` with the `Stairs` property set to `true` to create the dashed lines that mark the specified data point.  (An image of the resulting chart is attached at the end of answer).

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, TeeProcs, TeEngine, Chart, Series;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Chart1: TChart;
    LineSeries: TLineSeries;
    StairSeries: TFastLineSeries;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StairSeriesGetMarkText(Sender: TChartSeries; ValueIndex: Integer; var MarkText: string);

  private
   BottomMinimum : double;
   LeftMinimum : double;
   DataPoint : double;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


   function Fx(x : double) : double;

   begin
      Result := ((x - 1.5) * 20) + 17;
   end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin
   LineSeries.Clear;
   StairSeries.Clear;

   LeftMinimum   := 12;
   BottomMinimum := 1.25;

   DataPoint := 1.68;

   LineSeries.AddXY( 1.5, Fx(1.5) );
   LineSeries.AddXY( 1.6, Fx(1.6) );
   LineSeries.AddXY( 1.7, Fx(1.7) );

   StairSeries.AddXY( BottomMinimum, Fx(DataPoint) );
   StairSeries.AddXY( DataPoint,     Fx(DataPoint) );
   StairSeries.AddXY( DataPoint,     LeftMinimum   );


     Chart1.LeftAxis.SetMinMax( LeftMinimum,   LeftMinimum   + 12   );
   Chart1.BottomAxis.SetMinMax( BottomMinimum, BottomMinimum + 0.75 );
end;

procedure TForm1.StairSeriesGetMarkText(Sender: TChartSeries; ValueIndex: Integer; var MarkText: string);

begin
   if valueIndex = 0 then
      MarkText := '          '+Format('%5.2n',[ Fx(DataPoint) ])
   else if valueIndex = 1 then
      MarkText := ''
   else
      MarkText := '          '+Format('%5.2n',[ DataPoint ])
end;

end.
```

The DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 234
  Top = 127
  Width = 602
  Height = 533
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Chart1: TChart
    Left = 56
    Top = 24
    Width = 465
    Height = 409
    BackWall.Brush.Color = clWhite
    BackWall.Brush.Style = bsClear
    Title.Text.Strings = (
      'TChart')
    Legend.Visible = False
    View3D = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object LineSeries: TLineSeries
      Marks.ArrowLength = 8
      Marks.Visible = False
      SeriesColor = clBlue
      LinePen.Color = clBlue
      LinePen.Width = 4
      Pointer.InflateMargins = True
      Pointer.Style = psCircle
      Pointer.Visible = True
      XValues.DateTime = False
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Multiplier = 1.000000000000000000
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.DateTime = False
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Multiplier = 1.000000000000000000
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
    object StairSeries: TFastLineSeries
      Marks.ArrowLength = 8
      Marks.Transparent = True
      Marks.Frame.Visible = False  
      Marks.Visible = True
      SeriesColor = clRed
      OnGetMarkText = StairSeriesGetMarkText
      LinePen.Color = clRed
      LinePen.Style = psDash
      LinePen.Width = 2
      XValues.DateTime = False
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Multiplier = 1.000000000000000000
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.DateTime = False
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Multiplier = 1.000000000000000000
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
  end
end
```

Note: This is a Delphi 7 example that I originally built using Delphi 10.2 and tested it with Delphi 2007.  I downgraded the code to Delphi 7.

To use in Delphi 2007 or higher change the code that sets the Axes MinMax to this:

```
    Chart1.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(LeftMinimum,   LeftMinimum+12);
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(BottomMinimum, BottomMinimum+0.75);
```

The resulting chart should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! Thanks!